# flutter prefix with background color

Tags: flutter

Hi here is my code i want to create a prefix like the image i attached

```
`class NumberFiled extends StatelessWidget {
  const NumberFiled({Key? key, required this.lebal}) : super(key: key);
  final String lebal;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Text(
              "$lebal*",
              style: const TextStyle(color: whiltetextcolor),
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 15,
            ),
            TextField(
              style: const TextStyle(color: secondarycolor),
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              cursorColor: secondarycolor,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                prefix: Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                  color: secondarycolor,
                  child: const Text("+91"),
                ),
                focusedBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: whiltetextcolor)),
                enabledBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: whiltetextcolor, width: .2)),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ));
  }
}`
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U3TIY.jpg)

Hi here is my code i want to create a prefix like the image i attached

Answer (score 0):

> Widget _CountryCodeLabel() is your Country Code where you can set the color to the widget container.
>
> Widget _NumberInput() is your TextField

```
Row(crossAxisAlignment:CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                      mainAxisAlignment:
                                          MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                      children: [
                                        SizedBox(width: 6),
                                        _CountryCodeLabel(),
                                        VerticalDivider(
                                          color: Colors.grey,
                                          width: 1,
                                          thickness: 1,
                                        ),
                                        SizedBox(width: 8),
                                        Expanded(
                                          flex: 1,
                                          child: _NumberInput(),
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class NumberFiled extends StatelessWidget {
  const NumberFiled({Key? key, required this.lebal}) : super(key: key);
  final String lebal;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            Text(
              "$lebal*",
              style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 15,
            ),
            TextField(
              style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.amber),
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              cursorColor: Colors.amber,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                isDense: true,
                contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
                prefixIcon: Container(
                  height: 50,
                  width: 50,
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(3),
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.all(1),
                  decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.amber,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                      topLeft: Radius.circular(2),
                      bottomLeft: Radius.circular(2),
                    )
                  ),
                  child: const Center(child: Text("+91")),
                ),
                focusedBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white)),
                enabledBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white, width: .2)),
              ),)
          ],
        ));
  }
}
```

**Change you prefix to prefixIcon and give height and width of the Container in prefixIcon. Hope this will help you**